# How to I get just text value in an element

Tags: jquery, html

My html is:

```
<div>
   Some text
   <span>label text</span>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
??
```

I want output printed as -

```
"Some text"
```

When I do `$("div").text()`, I get `Some textLabel text`
and when I do `$("div").html()`, I get `Some text<span>Label text</span>`

Comment: @Alex - I did not understand. not('span') will check if the element is not a span. How is that going to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this plz:

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/f8VFf/ you can also look for `innerHTMl` and `outterHTML`

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};
alert($('div').justtext());​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. ;)

```
var tmp = $('div').clone();
tmp.children().remove();

alert(tmp.text());
```

Preview - http://jsfiddle.net/Z3qaN/

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
var txt = $('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});

alert(txt.text());
```